# I frequently face "Cannot find symbol", how to avoid it?

Tags: java, input, error-handling, java.util.scanner, symbols

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        do {
            Scanner asc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userTXT = asc.nextLine();
        } while(userTXT != "Twitter!");     
    }
}
```

The code is simple. Yet, there's `Cannot find symbol` for `userTXT`.
Any tip to avoid such Error is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't defined or initialised `userTXT` in a scope that can be seen from within the while loop.

You have defined it within the scope of the `while` loop which can't see variables defined inside it as the `while` loop and the variable are not in the same scope (`{}`).

Maybe try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userTXT = ""; // define it here (not necessarily with "" though)
        do {
            Scanner asc = new Scanner(System.in);
            userTXT = asc.nextLine();
        } while(!userTXT.equals("Twitter!"));
    }
}
```

Also you should use `.equals()` instead of `!=` when comparing Strings in Java.